# How can I override magento 2 adminhtml template file?

Tags: magento2

I want to override `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/items/renderer/default.html` file in magento 2. Please help.

Comment: Use this link to get answer to the above question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76434/how-to-extend-backend-template-files-in-magento-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the theme fallback as it works in the frontend

```
<config>
    <stores>
        <admin>
            <design>
                <theme>
                    <default>new_theme</default>
                </theme>
            </design>
        </admin>
    </stores>
</config>
```

then you can copy under the right path in the `app/design/adminhtml/default/new_theme/`